# Change pixel color with ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Say I have drawn a triangle with:

```
import flash.geom.Matrix;

function drawTriangle(sideLength:uint):void {
    var triangleHeight:uint = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideLength,2) - Math.pow(sideLength / 2,2));
    var triangleShape:Shape = new Shape();
    triangleShape.graphics.beginFill(0x2147AB);
    triangleShape.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xff00ff00);
    triangleShape.graphics.moveTo(sideLength/2, 0);
    triangleShape.graphics.lineTo(sideLength, triangleHeight);
    triangleShape.graphics.lineTo(0, triangleHeight);
    triangleShape.graphics.lineTo(sideLength/2, 0);
    addChild(triangleShape);

    var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix;
    matrix.translate(50, 50);
    transform.matrix = matrix;
}

drawTriangle(400);
```

**How can I achieve the following:**

When the user clicks a point inside the triangle, we will get the x and y coordinates, do some calculation with those values and get some (lots) of pixel coordiantes accordingly (all of those calculated points will be within the triangle). And finally, change the color of those points (something different than triangleShape fill color).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a triangle drawn to some `BitmapData`, added to a `Bitmap`, and then contained in a `Sprite`.

```
var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
box.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
box.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1);
box.graphics.moveTo(100, 50);
box.graphics.lineTo(50, 100);
box.graphics.lineTo(150, 100);
box.graphics.lineTo(100, 50);
box.graphics.endFill();
addChild(box);
var boxCopied:BitmapData = new BitmapData(box.width, box.height, true, 0x00000000);
var matr:Matrix = new Matrix();
matr.tx = -50;
matr.ty = -50;
boxCopied.draw(box, matr);
box.graphics.clear();
var boxCopy:Bitmap = new Bitmap(boxCopied);
box.addChild(boxCopy);
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked, false, 0, true);

function clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        var pixel = new Point(Math.floor(Math.random() * boxCopy.width), Math.floor(Math.random() * boxCopy.height));
        if(boxCopied.hitTest(new Point(boxCopy.x, boxCopy.y), 1, pixel))
        {
            boxCopied.setPixel32(pixel.x, pixel.y, Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF);
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.swfupload.com/view/162170.htm

Note I'm using `setPixel32` to send a 32-bit integer (essentially an ARBG instead of RGB) to manipulate alpha as well.

50 random pixels are being generated. If they're inside of the triangle, they're kept.

Comment: Please notice my most recent edit. I got pixel testing to work on a triangle.

Comment: Matt, how do I compare all the pixels in the triangle with the clicked pixel coordinate? (The comparision function is complicated, so I'm not including here.)

Comment: Are you comparing the clicked point to the triangle bounds? You would set pixel to be `new Point(mouseX, mouseY);` and remove the loop.

Comment: I need to get every single pixel's coordinate within the triangle, compare it with the clicked coordinates and change the colors accordingly.

Comment: By the way, I'm surprised that we make two copies to achieve the desired effect. Such things confuse me.

Comment: What you're describing is a more difficult problem that I won't be able to assist you with for a good period of time. Perhaps another question is in order.